# Extracting polygons with smaller polygons inside parcels with houses

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, overlapping-features, extract

I have cadastral map loaded as a pink vector layer in QGIS. Then I have another vector layer that contains residential houses (purple polygons).

I would like to create a new layer with areas containing houses. How can I do that in QGIS?

Illustration of the situation is depicted below
[image]

Comment: I would like to create a new layer with with areas containing houses

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the [Processing Toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html) and search for the "[Extract by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location)" tool.

Choose your cadastral layer as "Extract features from", "contain" as geometric predicate and your houses layer as "By comparing with features from":

[image]

Run it and done. You will get a new layer containing only the cadastral features which fully contain at least one house.

Comment: Thank you MrXsquared, that was what I nedeed.

Comment: @Vilem As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235